# If cell contains more codes of group 1 then group 2 or vice versa then it equals a different answer

Tags: excel, vba

***I changed the sub***

Right now, it stil does the same. I want to implement the COUNT.IF formula, maybe that will work.

```
If InStrFunc(Range(rcell.Address), "2528", "2529", "2530",
"2531", "2532", "2533", "2534", "2535", "2536", 
"2537", "2573", "2574") Then
   rcell.Offset(, 1) = "G1"
   Else: rcell.Offset(, 1) = "G2"
End If

If InStrFunc(Range(rcell.Address), "2549", "2550", "2551", 
"2552", "2553", "2554", "2555", "2556", "2557", 
"2558", "2561", "2567") Then
    rcell.Offset(, 1) = "G2"
    Else: rcell.Offset(, 1) = "G1"
```

_____________________________________.

I want to make a sub that will give the answer if the cell contains more codes for group 1 or group 2.

For example:

200,2530,2531,2552

2530 and 2531 are **group 1** and
2552 is **group 2**.

I used this code, which I found in an answer here, which only looks at the cell and if it contains codes it will give Group 1 because it finds one code in Group 1

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1")

Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = WS.Range("G2:G" & WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
For Each rcell In rng.Cells

If InStrFunc(Range(rcell.Address), "2528", "2529", "2530", "2531", "2532", "2533",
"2534", "2535", "2536", "2537", "2573", "2574") Then
   rcell.Offset(, 1) = "Group 1"
   Else: rcell.Offset(, 1) = "Group 2"
End If

Next rcell

End Sub
```

Another example:

601,2528,2549,2550,2552

2528 is **group 1** and 2549,2550,2552 are **group 2**.

The sub will put group 1 in the next cell even though there are more codes for group 2.

I hope that i explained it correctly.

Comment: So you need to loop through your list of codes and tot up how many are in each group and then see which is bigger and show that group. It's not clear from your description how these groups are defined.

Comment: What factor says if a number is group 1 or 2? Anyways, Split those numbers into an array, and count how many are group 1 and how many are group 2, and then decide.

Comment: @SJR G1 and G2 have each 10 different codes, all of them starting with 25xx. I need to find a way to count the codes. If a cell has 2 codes for G1 and 4 for G2. It should give G2, but it doesn't. I hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: Your current code doesn't distinguish between the groups. Do you have a problem adapting that code?

Comment: @SJR I changed the code so you can see which codes are for the groups.

Comment: Have you tried Luis's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**** UPDATE ******

try with something like this.

- fist creat an array with the values from cell
- then check one by one to see if is group1 ou group2 (and increment a counter for each one)
- then choose the biggest

  ```
  Dim WS As Worksheet
      Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1")

      Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
      Set rng = WS.Range("G2:G" & WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
      For Each

       rcell In rng.Cells

      Group = ""
      group1 = 0
      group2 = 0

      ValuesA = Split(Range(rcell.Address), ",")

      For Each Value In valuesA

      Select Case Value
         'list of values from Group 1
          Case "2528", "2529", "2530"
              group1 = group1 + 1

          'list of values from Group 2           
          Case "2532", "2533", "2534"
              group2 = group2 + 1
      End Select

  Next


   If group1 > group2 Then

      rcell.Offset(, 1) = "Group 1"

  Else
     rcell.Offset(, 1) = "Group 2"
  End If    
  Next rcell
  ```

#### OLD ANSWER

u can try with something like this

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1")

Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = WS.Range("G2:G" & WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
For Each rcell In rng.Cells

group=""

If InStrFunc(Range(rcell.Address), "2528", "2529", "2530", "2531", "2532", "2533",
"2534", "2535", "2536", "2537", "2573", "2574") Then
   group  = "Group 1"

End If

If InStrFunc(Range(rcell.Address), CODES_FOR_GROUP_2) Then
   group  = group & " " & "Group 2"

End If
   rcell.Offset(, 1) = group

Next rcell

End Sub
```

if a cell has the two groups it will show "Group 1 Group 2"

Comment: Thank you but, the problem here is that it has to count if there are more codes for group 1 or 2. This way it will just look at the cell and find a code for group 1 or 2.

Comment: i dont understant. u need to put the group that have more values, or u need to count and save the number of values for each group ?

Comment: It has to put in the group which has more values in the specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what yoou have tried, it looks like not always there is group 1 or 2.

Some values are not in any group (600, 200), so in those cases neither Group1 or Group2 total counts would be increased

I got this using a complex code

[image]

What I've done:

```
Sub test()
Dim idxGroup1 As Variant
Dim idxGroup2 As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim ZZ As Long
Dim xGroup1 As Long
Dim xGroup2 As Long
Dim Dict As Dictionary
Dim ArrayValues As Variant

Set Dict = New Dictionary

'all numbers from Group1
idxGroup1 = Array("2528", "2529", "2530", _
"2531", "2532", "2533", "2534", "2535", "2536", _
"2537", "2573", "2574")

'All numbers from Group2
idxGroup2 = Array("2549", "2550", "2551", _
"2552", "2553", "2554", "2555", "2556", "2557", _
"2558", "2561", "2567")

For i = LBound(idxGroup1) To UBound(idxGroup1) Step 1
    Dict.Add idxGroup1(i), "Group 1"
Next i

For i = LBound(idxGroup2) To UBound(idxGroup2) Step 1
    Dict.Add idxGroup2(i), "Group 2"
Next i

Erase idxGroup1
Erase idxGroup2

i = 1

Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
    'Reset counters
    xGroup1 = 0
    xGroup2 = 0
    ArrayValues = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ",")
    For ZZ = LBound(ArrayValues) To UBound(ArrayValues) Step 1
        If Dict.Exists(ArrayValues(ZZ)) = True Then
            If Dict(ArrayValues(ZZ)) = "Group 1" Then xGroup1 = xGroup1 + 1
            If Dict(ArrayValues(ZZ)) = "Group 2" Then xGroup2 = xGroup2 + 1
        End If
    Next ZZ
    Erase ArrayValues
    If xGroup1 > xGroup2 Then Cells(i, 2).Value = "Group 1"
    If xGroup1 < xGroup2 Then Cells(i, 2).Value = "Group 2"
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set Dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code takes all possible groups into arrays. Then those arrays are into a dictionary, where you can relate each value to a Group.

Later on, we split each single number in cell, and check with the dictionary if its belong to Group1, 2 or neither.

After that, we compare total counts and choose a winner (if there is a winner, it could be a tie).

You can easily adapt this code to your needs.